# Remove first part of each elements of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
Disable: 0
Lock: 0
Default: Value
ThisIsAnOption: foo
HereIsAnAnother: bar
AndAgain: foobar
```

And it countinues with more...

So now, I'm doing this to get the content into an array:

```
$file = './somefile.txt';
$array = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
```

With this result:

```
Array ( [0] => Disable: 0 [1] => Lock: 0 [2] => Default: Value [3] => ThisIsAnOption: foo [4] => HereIsAnAnother: bar [5] => AndAgain: foobar )
```

What I want to do is to keep in an array the values like the zeros, "Value", "foo", "bar" and "foobar". So I need to remove (with the space) the "Disable: ", "Lock: ", "..."

**EDIT: Here's the array that I want at the end**.

```
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => Value [3] => foo [4] => bar [5] => foobar )
```

What's the best way to do this? 
Thanks for all your help in advance!

Comment: I beleive that explode(": ",$array[$item]); will give you both values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr) + [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos):

```
<?php
// header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

$array = [
    'Disable: 0',
    'Lock: 0',
    'Default: Value',
    'ThisIsAnOption: foo',
    'HereIsAnAnother: bar',
    'AndAgain: foobar'
];

foreach($array as &$value){
    $value = substr($value, strpos($value, ':') + 2);
}

print_r($array);
?>
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 0
    [2] => Value
    [3] => foo
    [4] => bar
    [5] => foobar
)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <?php
$array = [
    'Disable: 0',
    'Lock: 0',
    'Default: Value',
    'ThisIsAnOption: foo',
    'HereIsAnAnother: bar',
    'AndAgain: foobar'
];

$arr_output = array(); 
foreach($array as $val)
{
   $arr_temp = explode(":", $val);
   if(isset($arr_temp[1]))
   {
       $arr_output[] = trim($arr_temp[1]);
   }
}
echo implode(",", $arr_output);
?>
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
0,0,Value,foo,bar,foobar
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/185317)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++)
{
    $temp = explode(': ', $array[$i]);
    $array[$i] = $temp[1];
}
```

This should basically divide the strings where there's a : followed by a space, thus deleting the space too.

Answer (score 0):

I have added the $array for this test case. You will use your array which has been read from the file.

```
$array = Array (
    0 => "Disable: 0",
    1 => "Lock: 0",
    2 => "Default: Value",
    3 => "ThisIsAnOption: foo",
    4 => "HereIsAnAnother: bar",
    5 => "AndAgain: foobar"
) ;
$newArray = array();

foreach ($array as $line) {
    if (strpos($line, ":")) {
        $lineArray = explode(":", $line);
        $newArray[trim($lineArray[0])] = trim($lineArray[1]);
    }
}
```

This gives this result:

```
    Disable 0
    Lock    0
    Default Value
    ThisIsAnOption  foo
    HereIsAnAnother bar
    AndAgain    foobar
    $newArray
```

**Unfortunately you have changed the requirements afterwards.**